# ¿Cómo insertar una alerta dentro de un input?

Tags: php, html, jquery

Tengo dos `input` para capturar un rango de fechas específico:

```html
Desde:
<input type="text" class="datepicker" id="start_date" name="start_date" value="<?php echo $START_DATE ;?>" placeholder="Elegir Fecha Inicial" required>
Hasta:
<input type="text" class="datepicker" id="end_date" name="end_date" value="<?php echo $END_DATE ; ?>" placeholder="Elegir Fecha Final" readonly="readonly" >
<input type="submit"id="btn_submit" value="Enviar"><br/>
```

... y una función de *JavaScript* para validar que si el campo de la fecha 'desde' es mayor que la fecha 'hasta', me muestre un `alert`:

```
$(function() {
  const textoIngresado = $("#start_date").val();
  const textoIngresado1 = $("#end_date").val();
  $("#btn_submit").on("click", function() {
    const textoIngresado = $("#start_date").val().split("-");
    const textoIngresado1 = $("#end_date").val().split("-");
    var fechaIngresada = new Date(
        textoIngresado[0], textoIngresado[1] - 1, textoIngresado[2]
    );
    var fechaLimite = new Date(
        textoIngresado1[0], textoIngresado1[1] - 1, textoIngresado1[2]
    );
    if (fechaIngresada > fechaLimite) {
        document.getElementById("start_date").setCustomValidity("Fecha Incorrecta");
      //alert("Fecha incorrecta"); 

    } 
  });
});
```

Lo que quiero **no es mostrar** un mensaje tipo `alert`, sino un mensaje como el que genera el atributo `required` en *HTML* al dejar un campo vacío.

[image: Campo de entrada.]

Comment: ¿vas a usar jquery o javascript puro?

Comment: Voy a usar JQuery

Comment: Ese mensaje sale porque estas usando la etiqueta *required*, y creo por el HTML5 lo reconocen los navegadores y mandan por defecto esas validaciones. ¿Es obligatorio que uses solo jQuery puro? o puedes usar alguna libreria?

Comment: Puedo Utilizar Cualquier Libreria. Solo quiero mostrar un mensaje de validacion igual o parecido al que genera el atributo Required en el input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para cambiar el mensaje generado por el atributo required debes usar [setCustomValidity()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/setCustomValidity) que recibe el texto que deseas que muestre. Debes tener en cuenta que esta función se usa por elementos del **`DOM`** y no directamente al elemento que obtienes por **`JQuery`**. Para hacerlo por JQuery tendrás que acceder al elemento de `index=0` que es lo que te devolvera el DOM con el cual lo podrás hacer.

```js
$(function() {
  const textoIngresado = $("#start_date").val();
  const textoIngresado1 = $("#end_date").val();
  $("#btn_submit").on("click", function() {
  debugger;
    const textoIngresado = $("#start_date").val().split("-");
    const textoIngresado1 = $("#end_date").val().split("-");
    var fechaIngresada = new Date(
      textoIngresado[0], textoIngresado[1] - 1, textoIngresado[2]
    );
    var fechaLimite = new Date(
      textoIngresado1[0], textoIngresado1[1] - 1, textoIngresado1[2]
    );
    if (fechaIngresada > fechaLimite) {
      document.getElementById("start_date").setCustomValidity("mensaje de prueba");
      //mensaje de alerta
    }
  });
});
```

```css
document.getElementById("start_date").setCustomValidity("mensaje de prueba");
//$("#start_date")[0].setCustomValidity("mensaje de prueba 2");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  Desde: Desde:
  <input type="text" class="datepicker" id="start_date" name="start_date" value="2018-11-11" placeholder="Elegir Fecha Inicial" required> Hasta:
  <input type="text" class="datepicker" id="end_date" name="end_date" value="2018-10-10" placeholder="Elegir Fecha Final" readonly="readonly">
  <input type="submit" id="btn_submit" value="Enviar"><br/>
</form>
```

Comment: bercklyn Carlosviza Entendiendo lo que tratas hacer, y si lo quiero como  lo hiciste en el codigo, pero no me sirvio con los input de las fechas.

Comment: @EdgarYezidCruz puedes actualizar el código de tu pregunta con lo que intentaste para ver mejor por que no te sale.

Comment: Ya Actualice el codigo editado.

Comment: @EdgarYezidCruz ya actualice mi código y no me dio problemas.Lo que puede estar pasando es que no incluyas tus inputs dentro de un formulario o el navegador que usas no sea el compatible.

Comment: Tienes razòn, en mi codigo utilizo formularios, pero al eliminarlo me funciono correctamente.